# Exceptions codes for Web Services using Java

Tags: java, web-services, exception

I´m developping a Web Services Project and I have to insert a specific code for each exception. In my response I have to get something like this:

```
<Response xmlns="http://localhost/webservices/blabla/method">
   <error><100>Must introduce something</100></error>
</Response>
```

There is a simple way to achieve this? For code error there is some kind of good pratices, like 120 for Exception, or 213 for EJBException?

Comment: Read this link http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-enrichment.html#unique-error-codes 
It talks about Exception Enrichment and about identifying an exception with an unique error code.
Also you can read this link http://northconcepts.com/blog/2013/01/18/6-tips-to-improve-your-exception-handling/
I hope it helps.